# Can someone evaluate this in wolfram alpha and get the result!!. I tried but does not seem to understand the query

Tags: combinatorics

$\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k = 1}^{50} \sum_{n = 1}^{{{\frac{k+1}{2}}}} k{k\choose n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-n}$

Comment: I do not know how to put floor function in the inner sum where you have $\frac{k+1}{2}$.  May that is the itch!

Comment: Just typing  Floor[.], I suppoose

Comment: May be, you need to consider separatly the case where $k$ is odd and the case where $k$ is even.

Comment: Yes, You are right.  I shall do that!!